# debezium table whitelist with regular expression

Tags: regex, debezium

I have some database table with bg_ and cp_ prefix like "bg_table1", "bg_table2" and "cp_table1".There are also some other tables without any prefix such as my_table1, user_action and so forth.

I have two debezium postgreSQL connectors and trying to configure `table.whitelist` property by following Debezium - http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#connector-properties. My requirements are as follows:

- in the first connector I want to load the tables whose names start with **bg_** or **cp_**
- in the second connector I want to load the rest of the tables - **does not** start with **bg_** or **cp_**

I am using something like below in the connector configuration but does not work:

First Connector Config:

```
"table.whitelist": "public.bg_*,public.cp_*"
```

Second Connector Config:

```
"table.whitelist": ""  Cannot figure out need your help
```

It would be great if someone could help me figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For your second connector you could use `table.blacklist` instead of specifying a whitelist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this for your whitelist:

```
"table.whitelist": "public\.(bg|cp)_.*"
```

### Demo

And try this for your blacklist:

```
"table.whitelist": "public\.(?!(bg|cp)_)[^_]+_.*"
```

### Demo

The first pattern should pretty much work on any regex engine.  The second pattern uses a negative lookahead.  It would only work if your regex engine supported that.  If it doesn't, then it will be harder to write a pattern with the logic you want to use.

Note: In the context of Java code you may need to double up backslashes to escape things like dots.  That is, you might have to use the following version, e.g.

```
"table.whitelist": "public\\.(bg|cp)_.*"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, it shows following error while registering the connector : javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized character escape '.' (code 46). Any clue

Comment: Yes, try using two backslashes to escape the dot, e.g. `\\.` q.v. my updated answer.